# Definition by primitive recursion confusion

Tags: recursion, computability

In the below text, I don't see why the red boxed equation satisfies a definition by primitive recursion.

In this case, the definition says: $ \ \   g(0)=f(n)=0$, $ \ \ $  $g(n+1) = h(n,g(n))$.

I can see what $f$ should be, but what is the function $h$ here?

It seems to be some composition involving the $add$ function, but I don't see how to 'turn' $\chi_{E}(\text{succ}(n)) \ $ into $n$, if that makes sense...  Thanks.

EDIT:  $E$ is the set of even natural numbers.

---

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to turn $\chi_E(\mathrm{succ}(n))$ into $n$? You don't need that. You need to turn $n$ into $\chi_E(\mathrm{succ}(n))$ and it is pretty evident how to do so.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see what you mean.

Comment: You want to define $g(n+1)= h(n,g(n))$ and $h$ is a function of two arguments and one argument is $n$ already.

Comment: @NikPronko   I understand this, but what has it got to do with the problem?  Can you please write down the rule of the function $h$, using the add, X_E and succ functions, please?   I get   $ \ \ h(n, g(n))= \text{add}(\chi_E(\text{succ}(n)), g(n))$.  But this is wrong, as the first argument of the RHS is not $n$, it's a function of $n$.  What am I missing?

Comment: $h \neq \mathrm{add}$

Comment: Are you confused about why the recursive solution is equivalent to the definition, or are you confused as to why the red boxed equation is considered primitive recursive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

$$h(n,a) = a +  \chi_E(\mathrm{succ}(n)) = \mathrm{add}(P^2_1(a,n), \chi_E(\mathrm{succ}(P^2_2(a,n))),$$

where $P^n_i$ is a projection function, which is considered primitive recursive by default.

Then plugging $a = g(n)$ into $h$ gives you recursion step:

$$ h(n,g(n)) = g(n) + \chi_E(\mathrm{succ}(n)) = g(n + 1)  $$

Comment: I almost want to say "but that is cheating..."  Obviously, I haven't understood this topic properly enough.  I'll go revise the basics some more.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: you can use composition to define primitive recursive functions

Comment: Well, from my understanding, we can use composition only when we are using the *Substitution* definition to prove primitive recursive functions.  But, from what I get of the primitive **recursion** definition, Substitutions shouldn't be allowed like you just used it here.   In fact,  $g(n+1)$ still doesn't satisfy the definition $h(n, g(n))$.  In fact, you applied the Substitution definition instead of finding a rule for $h$ that satisfies $g(n)+ \chi_E (\text{succ}(n)) $.  I'm not sure that's okay.

Comment: The Substitution definition is :  $g(n_1,n_2,...,n_k)=f(h_1(n_1,n_2,...,n_k),...,h_t(n_1,n_2,...,n_k))$.  If a function $g$ satisfies this equation, then it's primitive recursive.   However, the primitive recursion definition works in a different way.

Comment: I understand now, thanks again for the help.

Comment: glad that you got rid of your confusion.